# How to use OGNL index reference operator

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

Working with OGNL you can reference action context objects like `#application`, `#session`,`#root`, `#action`,`#request`,`#parameters`,`#attr`, and the action context with `#context`.

> The framework sets the OGNL context to be our ActionContext, and the
>   value stack to be the OGNL root object.

And OGNL uses `[]` as index reference to access an object properties. For example if the object `foo` has a property `bar` then it can access like `foo.bar` or `foo['bar']`. It also works if `foo` is a map and `bar` is a key.

Now, I want to put a variable and a value to the value stack context like that

```
<s:set var="bar" value="'hello'"/>
<s:set var="foo" value="'bar'"/>
```

and print the value

```
<s:property value="%{#attr[#foo]}"/>
```

It should print `hello`.

I'd like to know how this works. I know that `#attr` is an object that doesn't have a property referenced by `#foo`, i.e. `bar`. However this works. It also works if I use `#request` and `#context`, and probably `#root` instead of `#attr`. Neither of this objects has a property `bar`, but OGNL thinks otherwise.  I'd like to know what OGNL thinks about property of the object it references and why this expression is working. Also if there are alternative ways to print `hello` using `#foo` reference in OGNL expression.

Comment: Where the variables will be stored if `scope` isn't specified in `<s:set>` tag?

Comment: It will store in the value stack context, I have mentioned it.

Comment: Well not exactly. The value will be put into the value stack context map **and** will be set in the stack with the `#attr[var]` expression.

Comment: The value stack context is a map, with the expression I don't set but get the variable and then the value.

Comment: What? Have you understood what set tag does?

Comment: Forget for the moment about more difficult case and try `<s:property value="#attr.foo"/>`. Do you understand why it returns `bar`?

Comment: Yes, and I mentioned it in many of my answers, but you never, doesn't matter, I think I explained enough to understand what I want. I will also answer you questions if you have. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: @AleksandrM Can you elaborate what `#attr.foo` is doing? Also with conjunction of what `#context` and `#request` are doing, and how it differs?

Comment: The `#request.foo` gets request attribute with name `foo` from the request. The `#context.foo` gets value from OGNL context value map with key `foo`. And `#attr.foo` tries to get value from page context, then from the request, then from the session and then from application scope.

Comment: That's right, but it's not what I have asked. What will return the `#request.foo` if it doesn't have attribute with name `foo`? Why it returns `bar`?

Comment: Because this is how S2 request wrapper is implemented, if request attribute isn't found then it gets value from the value stack. This is basics of Struts2.

Comment: @AleksandrM Request wrapper is different object, `#request` refers to request map. How it gets or not gets the value from the value stack is a question I asked. I want the explanation.

Comment: And where from request map will get its values? :)

Comment: @AleksandrM Well, now I think it's different story for each objects that works. Request map is getting values from request wrapper, don't know why, it should already have all request attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given expression `<s:property value="#attr[#foo]"/>` the part inside `[]` will be evaluated first. The `#foo` is resolved to `bar` so expression becomes `#attr['bar']` (which is equivalent to `#attr.bar`).

Using `#attr.bar` the value for `bar` will be searched until it is found in the page context, then in the `request`, then in the `session` and then in the `application` scope.

The `#context.bar` gets value from OGNL context value map with key `bar`.

The `#request.bar` tries to get request attribute with name `bar` from the request map and if it isn't found then `bar` will be searched in the value stack. This happens in Struts2 request wrapper implementation.

Comment: Can you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067412/struts2-jsp-el-concatenation-doesnt-seem-to-work) one? I have a similar problem.