# JSP Unterminated <s:a> Tag With Nested OGNL

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have some OGNL I am using to populate the href element of an `<s:a>` to a dynamically produced URL, handled by the Google UserService.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="requestUri" value="%{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'].requestURI}" />
<s:a href="%{#action.userService.createLoginURL("<c:out value="${requestUri}"/>");}">Sign in</s:a>
```

However, I am getting an error saying the `<s:a>` tag is unterminated. I have tried escaping inner speechmarks, and using single quotes but so far I have always been greeted with the same error message.

```
(11,71) Unterminated &lt;s:a tag
```

I can't for the life of me see what is wrong. Maybe someone with better eyes for the language will see something I cannot.

Comment: @AleksandrM Rolled back because OP is using Struts2 and OGNL. Don't close questions that I was answered, don't edit tags to remove relevant ones.

Comment: @RomanC Not S2 or OGNL related. Jsp tags cannot be nested like that.

Comment: OP was using Struts2 tags, that doesn't work without struts2

Comment: `<c:out>` isn't a S2 tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM You should look better.

Comment: @AleksandrM Please stop rollback questions that I was answered.

Comment: @RomanC It is not about you. It is about question. No OGNL there and jsp tags cannot be nested like that.

Comment: @AleksandrM %{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'].requestURI} not OGNL?

Comment: @RomanC Hmmm It is hard to say. It is used in jstl tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM it's a string, the second tag is `s:a` where OP was trying to use it.  The title also shows that the question is using OGNL.

Comment: @RomanC Nested ognl? Maybe you should add info to your answer about where ognl can be used.

Comment: @AleksandrM Is it what you asked?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107138/discussion-between-aleksandr-m-and-roman-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use JSP tags in Struts tag's attributes, but you can use OGNL there.

Also note, that you can use OGNL *only* in Struts tag's attributes. And in most cases OGNL is executed once on the server, you shouldn't use nested OGNL or whatever you call it. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23919226/573032) question will show you how to use you called *nested OGNL*.

```jsp
<s:set var="requestUri" value="%{#context['com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'].requestURI}" />
<s:a href="%{#action.userService.createLoginURL(#requestUri)}">Sign in</s:a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Roman :)
This allowed me to compile and deploy, but the link is blank i.e not a hyperlink, just plain text in an <a> tag.
Any ideas what the problem could be here?

Comment: Why it should be blank if the objects have appropriate getters?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok problem solved.
Turns out the c:out wasn't needed to output the value of requestUri. It could simply be left as-is to be evaluated with the rest of the expression