# Retrieve field from value stack passed through Tiles

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles, ognl, valuestack

I'm using Tiles 2.0 with Struts2 and what I'm trying to do is populate an action bean from the value stack, i.e.

```
<s:property value="myBean.cod1"/>
```

would populate something like `AS0000123`

Now, what happens if in my tile's definition I have something like this:

```xml
<definition name="fieldPurpose1" template="fieldPurposeTemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="field" value="myBean.cod1"/>
</definition>
```

And so, in the template I'm trying to:

```jsp
<s:set name="fieldSimple"><tiles:insertAttribute name="field"/></s:set>
<s:property value="%{#fieldSimple}"/>
```

But what I get is the text `myBean.cod1` not the populated one.
Any ideas?

Comment: The thing is that in the jsp i don't know the name of the bean's field i'm trying to populate, it is parametrized through a tiles definition and the problem is than i can't use that parametrized value to retrieve the value of the bean's field. I have tried several ways, but they all fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is the key, and you can use this key to find another value using [OGNL index reference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23919226/573032).

```jsp
<s:set name="fieldSimple"><tiles:insertAttribute name="field"/></s:set>
<s:property value="%{#attr[#fieldSimple]}"/>
```